# Override application.properties for integration tests in spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a standard `spring-boot` app and I want to use MS SQL database for the production environment, whereas for integration tests I'd like to use `h2` databse. The problem is that I wasn't able to find out, how to override the default `application.properties` file. Even though I was trying to follow some tutorials, I didn't come up with the right solution...maybe I'm just missing something...

The main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

and the class with tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class MessageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MessageRepository messageRepository;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    @Test
    public void testSomething(){
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

So the question is, how to force the spring-boot to use `application-test.properties` file when running the tests, instead of `application.properties`, which should be used during the run time.

I tried for example to replace `@WebIntegrationTest` annotation with `@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")`, but this results in `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Have you tried to use specific profiles ?

Comment: No, since I'm pretty new to this technology and I actually don't know what is the best way to achieve this..

Comment: The above comment *is* the answer to your question, as per the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was pretty easy...after several hours of trying, I've realized that I just needed to annotate my test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation.

```
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
    @WebIntegrationTest
    public class MessageControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        MessageRepository messageRepository;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        @Test
        public void testSomething(){
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: A slightly better way would be to do something like this: @ActiveProfiles(AppProfile.TEST) .ie create an enum with all the possible states. It saves time on changes and make tracking profile types easier. Also create an abstract BaseTest class and put all these settings there. Now extend all your test cases from it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a application-test.properties file in your app.

I do it in two ways :

1.CLI JVM Args

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

2. add the application-test.properties as an active profile.

add the `spring.profiles.active=test` in the application.properties and it will load your application-test.properties file.

3. As you pointed to in your answer annotate a class test with a specific active profile ( which is not suitable when having a large test classes i think ) `@ActiveProfiles("test")`

Comment: Please validate the answer if it suits to you